# How to generate a input file for gaussian in Avogadro 2?

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, gaussian, avogadro

I made auto optimization working by installing openbabel using `sudo apt install openbabel`.

Is there any way to make Gaussian extension working by doing something?

I've the `avogenerators` scripts in `/home/jupiter/.local/share/OpenChemistry/Avogadro/inputGenerators/OpenChemistry-avogenerators-eddfee4`.

Please help me to generate input file for gaussian, ASAP.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your problem the same one described in this past question? [How to make the input generator plugin work in Avogadro 2 on GNU/Linux?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2163/243). The solution is to compile Avogadro 2 from source.

Comment: What version of Avogadro2 do you have installed? How did you install it? The latest version (1.95.1) fixes a number of packaging bugs related to input generators.

Answer (score 5):

You can use OpenBabel directly to obtain the Gaussian input from command line.

OpenBabel supports two types of Gaussian input generation:

- Gaussian 98/03 Cartesian Input
- Gaussian Z-matrix Input

To run OpenBabel:

```
obabel [-i<input-type>] <infilename> [-o<output-type>] -O<outfilename> [Options]
```

Take a look at [this](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/4738/24) answer for information about all the formats OpenBabel work with.